# Secure wipe a directory

Tags: c#, security, cryptography, directory, delete-file

I know how to wipe a file in C# including it's sectors and such.

But how do I overwrite the directories themselves?

Example: `@"C:\mydirectory\"` must be unrecoverable gone forever (all files insides are already wiped) so that it will be impossible to recover the directory structure or their names.

------------------- Update below (comment formatting is such a hassle so I post it here)---

For the file deletion I look up the partition's cluster and section size's and overwrite it at least 40 times using 5 different algorithms where the last algorithm is always the random one. The data is also actually written to the disk each time (and not just in memory or something). The only risk is that when I wipe something the physical address on the disk of that file could theoretically have been changed. The only solution I know for that is to also wipe the free disk space after the file has been wiped and hope that no other file currently partially holds the old physical location of the wiped file. Or does Windows not do such a thing?

[http://www.sans.org/reading_room/whitepapers/incident/secure-file-deletion-fact-fiction_631](http://www.sans.org/reading_room/whitepapers/incident/secure-file-deletion-fact-fiction_631%20%20states:) states:

*"It is important to note the consensus that overwriting the data only reduces the
likelihood of data being recovered. The more times data is overwritten, the more
expensive and time consuming it becomes to recover the data. In fact Peter Guttman
states “…it is effectively impossible to sanitize storage locations by simple overwriting
them, no matter how many overwrite passes are made or what data patterns are written.”3 Overwritten data can be recovered using magnetic force microscopy, which
deals with imaging magnetization patterns on the platters of the hard disk. The actual
details of how this is accomplished are beyond the scope of this paper."*

Personally I believe that when I overwrite the data like 100+ times using different (maybe unknown) algorithms (and if there is no copy of the data left elsewhere like in the swap files) that it will take any very expensive team of professionals many many years to get that data back. And if they do get the data back after all those years then they deserve it I guess... That must be a project for life.

So:

- wiping unused data: use cipher (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315672) or fill the hard-disk with 4GB files or use the Eraser command line executable.
- wiping swap files: ?
- wiping bad sectors: ?
- wiping directories: use Eraser (as Teoman Soygul stated)
- How do we know for sure that we overwrote the actual physical addresses?
- wiping the most recently used files and the Windows log files should of course be piece a cake for any programmer :)
- Eraser solves most of the above problems but cannot wipe the pages files. So any forensic will still find the data back if it was in those swap files at any moment.
- AFAIK eraser does not wipe the file allocation tables. But I'm not sure.

And the conclusion should then be: It's (near) impossible to secure wipe in C#?

Comment: Sorry to say but 'secure' wipen doesn't really exist. So should overwrite the bytes of the old file a couple of times to at least make the recover difficult.

Comment: Write over its MFT entry in the master file table? Though I have no idea if C# grants any kind of access to the MFT.

Comment: @PeteyB - I'm not sure what you're suggesting.  If it's to say that whatever method you use will be reliant upon the MFT entry being nuked, that is entirely insecure.  Unless the data itself is erased in a secure manner, it will still be recoverable.

Comment: Please specify the file systems or platforms you're trying to cover - directory storage methods differ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no general approach for this ... consider a SSD: you can't even make sure that your write operation will write to the same physical address, because of wear-levelling methods

Comment: I updated my first post since a reply in this comment box is really frustrating. But I'm afraid that it is near impossible :(. There is not even commercial software that can perform a 100% SECURE wipe. Aren't there any forums that discuss secure wiping into every detail or some documents online? Preferably for Windows as Unix is different.

Comment: when it comes to military grade applications, the usual solution is to destroy the media that contains the data. according to what i've seen so far this seems to be the only secure approach.

Answer (score 1):

If all files/folders inside the folder is already wiped (as you stated), all that is left is the directory itself. Using a cryptic random number generator rename the directory and delete it. It will be as good as wiped.

If this isn't enough for you, grab a copy of [Eraser](http://www.heidi.ie/eraser/) command line executable and execute the command:

```
Process.Start("eraserl.exe", @"-folder "C:\MyDirectory\" -subfolders -method DoD_E -silent");
```

Comment: Renaming a directory isn't enough. The directory structure would still be visible. Maybe renaming it enough will at least wipe the name of the directory.

Eraser would work but then I'd have to use an external program for something so simple. Is there no way in C# to get the location of the bytes or something that hold the data that represents the directory?

Comment: Well then recursively rename the whole directory structure, or let eraser handle it for your.

Answer (score 0):

Securely deleting is not straightforward, as you know. So it may be worth considering an alternative strategy.

Have you considered using something like [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) to create an encrypted volume? You could store the files there, then use standard delete routines. An adversary would then need to both decrypt the encrypted volume AND recover the deleted files.

Comment: I cannot embed TrueCrypt in C# AFAIK. Aside from that, is that safe? Does TrueCrypt take things like the swap files and the bad sectors problem in mind?

Comment: @user653160. Nothing (to my knowledge) will prevent Windows from placing data into a swap file. Still, TrueCrypt could be the answer - you'd probably be looking at either whole disk encryption, or at least putting the swap file into an encrypted partition. Using TrueCrypt requires no special implementation with regards to c#/any language. You just write/read files as normal, but to/from an encrypted volume.